# Logarithm of a Unitary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a $n \times n$ complex unitary matrix. Show that $U$ has a logarithm. That is $$U=e^V, \text{ where } V \text{ is an } n \times n \text{ complex matrix }$$.

**My approach**
I used the theorem that states if $A, B$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices, and $B$ is invertible then $$e^{BAB^{-1}}=Be^AB^{-1}$$

After using the above theorem I ended up with getting :
$$ e^U=Ue^UU^{-1}=V(\text{ let )}$$

I am not getting $e^V=U$.

I do not know how to use the condition that $U$ is unitary.

Comment: Hint: Unitary matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: How to proceed using this?

Comment: Do you know the exponential of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I proved that every Unitary matrix can be expressed as $e^{iA}$ , where $A$ Is a Hermitian matrix and then I assumed $iA=V$.

Comment: Sounds good. You might consider writing down your proof as self-answer to this question.